# How to get the selected value using angu-complete alt?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angucomplete-alt for a drop down in my angularjs project. And using the selected object in another place.

```
 <angucomplete-alt id="ex1"
                 placeholder="Select State"
                 selected-object="selectedState"
                 local-data="state"
                 search-fields="description"
                 title-field="description"
                 minlength="1"
                 inputclass="form-control form-control-small"
                 match-class="highlight" 
                 input-changed="inputChanged"    
                />
```

JS:

```
 $scope.selectedState = function (selected) {
   console.log(selected);
 };
```

Here, if the user selects an option in drop down for the first time, (Say, America), its printing as America. But if the user without refreshing selecting again with another value, (Say London), its not printing anything. I need to trigger this, every time the user selects the value from the drop down. How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a $watch in scope like this:

```
$scope.$watch('selectedState', function(new, old) {
  console.log(new);
});
```